# Compiler issue when using wildcard boolean in higher order function

Tags: scala

Using scala 2.12 if I try the following code:

```
 val v = Vector(true, false, false, true)
 val c: Int = v.count(_)
```

It gives me a compiler error and I have to do the following to make it compile:

```
val c: Int = v.count(_ == true)
```

Why is this?

Comment: You can use `identity` function. Just passing underscore without anything else it will return a function. `v.count(identity)` should solve the problem

Comment: This is because the `_` syntax is more tricky than what you think _(which is why I dislike it)_. `v.count(_)` does not expand to `v.count(x => x)` which is what you want, but rather to `x => v.count(x)` and then that produces a type mismatch with the expected type of `c`